# Data binding / populate items in listbox in windows phone

Tags: data-binding, listbox, windows-phone

i have two separate classes namely:

```
    public class Floor { 
     private string fname;
   public Floor(string name)
   {
     fname = name;
   }

   public int FName
   {
      set { fname = value; }
      get { return fname; }
   }

}

public class Building 
{
   List<Floor> floors;
   string _bName;

   public Building(string bname)
   {

       _bName = bname;

      floors = new List<Floors>();

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
           floors.Add(new Floor("floor" + (i + 1)));
      }
   }

   public string BName
   {
      set{ _bName = value; }
      get{ return _bName; }
   }

   public List<Floor> Floors
   {
      set { floors = value; }
      get { return floors; }
   }

}
```

in my XAML (MainPage.xaml):

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstBuilding" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,0,15">                  
           <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BName }" />                                                                                      
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and in my XAML.cs (MainPage.xaml.cs)

```
ObservableCollection< Building > buildings = new ObservableCollection< Building>();

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    buildings.Add(new Building("building" + (i + 1)));
}

lstBuilding.ItemsSource = buildings
```

Here's the question:

how can i access FName inside Floor class using XAML?
What i did is :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Floors.FName }" />
```

but it didn't work. :(

Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code itself is flawed because you are trying to access Floors which is again a Collection/List, When  you have `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Floors.FName }" />`  , it is not clear which floor are you referring to or what you are trying to do?

If you want reference to the first floor only you can try  `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Floors[0].FName }" />`

But incase you are trying to access data of each floor in each building you need to change the xaml for that to work. Its called Nested binding.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBuilding">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Floors}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FName}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```